Is there exist a command to stop compiling?
I am designing a .cls file, and I need to add a judgement that if a bool value is true, then do nothing; if a bool value is false, then return an error.
I put this \bool_if: judgement just after LoadClass{report}, and there's also \RequirePackage{hyperref} behind. I intentionally triggered the error condition, but there are not only my error message, but warning messages
Package hyperref: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.
Package rerunfilecheck: File `hduthesis-bc.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)    Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)    or use package `bookmark'.

I think this is caused by nonstopmode in my latexworkshop .json file. So, except use the compile option like stop on first error, is there exist a macro to force stop current compile? Just like a command named \stopcompile
\bool_if:NF \g__skyrmion_tmp_bool
  {
    \skyrmion_msg_error:nn { <module> } { <> }
    \stopcompile
  }

In order to force stop current compiling, and so that packages and other contents in the remain part of my .cls file will not be loaded.

Isn't this the purpose of critical and/or fatal?  error just "interrupt[s] the TEX run without ending it".  Or are you looking for something else?

i doubt this is a "core" question...

Depending on the behaviour that you want.
\@@end

is the TeX primitive \end which stops the run (but can itself generate Tex errors if called at the wrong place)
Or like iftex package you can use
    \batchmode\read -1 to \@tempa

This forces a hard stop in almost all cases (by switching to batch mode then requesting user input which is disabled in that mode)
But I would not do this. A normal LaTeX (or expl3) error should be enough. That does by default give an error message and stop TeX. If you (or your editor) choose to run TeX in a mode that scrolls past errors then hopefully you know that is what you have done and expect that to happen.
Forcing a hard stop that forces no output and does not allow any interaction or scrolling past the error is not the expected behaviour in most cases.
iftex package only uses this in commands such as
\RequireLuaTeX

which is a command explicitly designed to stop with no recovery if the document is not being processed by luatex.
